# Can I use TypeScript without RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two classes in different files:

```
export class ActionsCollection{
    constructor(greeting :string){
        this.greet(greeting);
    }

    public greet(greeting :string) {
        return "<h1>"+greeting+"</h1>";
    }
}
```

And

```
import {ActionsCollection} from "./actionsCollection";

class Greeter extends ActionsCollection{
    constructor(public greeting: string) {
        super(greeting);
    }
}

alert(new Greeter("Hello, world!"));
```

`Greeter` is generated in such a file in which there is require line `("./ actionsCollection")`. But I want to make sure that all the files (*.ts) generates in only one file main.js, it does not need `require`.
Can I do that? And if so, how?

PS: At the same time, for the assembly, you can use standard [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm) tools and Gulp. And *nothing* more, besides modules for Gulp.

Comment: If you use "files" in tsconfig and you write all files in the correct order it will compile everything in a single file (of course having the "out" directive in your tsconfig.json). The problem with this approach is that you cannot forget any file in the list. Using ES6 imports should be enough if you indicate your entry point though

Comment: You can use the gulp webpack module I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

`import {ActionsCollection} from "./actionsCollection";`

with

`/// <reference path="./actionsCollection.ts" />`.

See [Triple Slashes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) for more info on using the triple slash imports.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to make sure that all the files (*.ts) generates in only one file main.js, it does not need require. Can I do that? And if so, how

You can use it quite easily with [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack): https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

This has the additional advantage that you can use all the wonderful libraries on npm seamlessly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I can only use the Gulp, due restrictions in the draft.  I said about this in my question

Answer (score -1):

The [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html) file may help you.

It has an "out" g.

Comment: I do this: `"files": [
        "core.ts",
        "sys.ts",
        "types.ts",
        "scanner.ts",
        "parser.ts",
        "utilities.ts",
        "binder.ts",
        "checker.ts",
        "emitter.ts",
        "program.ts",
        "commandLineParser.ts",
        "tsc.ts",
        "diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts"
    ]` And this not work